# Include Animated .svg into unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector-graphics, svg-animate

I want to include animated .svg in my UNITY project. I have imported vector graphics package to UNITY. I have an animated .svg file that runs properly in browser but when I add this .svg file to UNITY it is displayed properly but does not animates.
How do i play animated .svg file?

Answer (score 1):

SVG Animations are not supported, yet. ([unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@1.0/manual/index.html))